# MSM Upgrade from EE 2x to EE 3.5.16, now can only see primary site

Tags: multi-site-manager

I upgraded from EE 2x, to EE 3.5.16. I can see my primary site fine, but the other sites (both index.php and admin.php) say:

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

So I have checked all the usual - open_basedir looks ok (has not changed):

```
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}:/var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/:/var/www/vhosts/site2.com/httpdocs/
```

Folder permissions are 755 on site1.

Just to check the system_path, in index.php for domain2, I have added:

```
echo SYSPATH.'ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php';
```

And this shows the correct path when I access index.php i.e.

> /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/httpdocs/softwater/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php

I can access the domain2 control panel by first logging into the domain1 control panel.

I'm truly stumped. Everything was working fine with EE2 - what could have gone wrong?

Comment: You are very sure the index.php in your second site is the correct, EE3 version index.php file? It isn't the same as the EE2 version index.php file.

Comment: Yes, positive it's the EE3 version.

Comment: The other thing that's changed is I've gone from PHP 5.4.16 mod_php to PHP 7.2.7 FPM application. Would that make a difference?

Comment: No, although you are likely to run into issues with third-party addons with a change like that, it wouldn't cause this issue. Are you sure the correct file/folder owner is set on your entire web root? This is one of those issues that is hard to dig into with access to the machine as I can't imagine how I'd recreate it.

Comment: And are you sure you have have the correct license key for your purchase? When you upgrade from EE2 -> EE3, if you have MSM, you have to purchase the upgraded MSM license as well.

Comment: I definitely have the correct owner on the entire web root. Just checked the license key it was the wrong one. I have entered the correct key, but I've already had to roll back to EE2x for further testing so can't tell if it has made a difference. Would having the wrong key cause an error in EE3, despite it working in EE2?

Comment: Or is it that the key was correct for EE2, and it changes when you upgrade to EE3?

Comment: Visit expressionengine.com and make sure you download and install the correct EE3 key, and verify that it is for a purchase that includes however many MSM accounts you have. Yes, there is a chance EE3 will bounce index.php from another site if you don't have the correct license with more than one site available.

Comment: I checked on my EE3 dev environment, and it's showing the correct key for EE3 with the correct number of sites allowed, yet my test secondary site doesn't work. I guess the key changes when upgrading from EE2 to EE3, and that was a red herring.

Comment: You may have covered this already - but the index.php file for domain2 is not the same as a normal index.php file, nor is it the same as the index.php file for the main site.  Might be worth checking that your admin.php and index.php files for the second site conform to requirements set out in EE docs - https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/msm/domainsetup.html

Comment: Yes, index.php (and admin.php) for site2 definitely conforms to those instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the following:

```
setfacl -R -m u:site2-user:rwX /var/www/vhosts/site1.com/
```